# Extract AND condition in SQL statement via java regex

Tags: java, sql, regex

i want to get sql `and` conditions in a sql statement

Input:

`And tbl.col1='Jim And Tom' and tbl.col2 like '%Test' AND tbl.col3 >='2018-12-12' And tbl.col4 Like 'what's this'`

Expected output

```
tbl.col1='Jim And Tom'

tbl.col2 like '%Test'

tbl.col3 >='2018-12-12'

tbl.col4 Like 'what's this'
```

Btw, i have tried java split to do this, but if the keyword contains `and`, it will not work

```
String[] subFilters = Pattern.compile("\\s*and\\s*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).split(filter);
```

If it's possible to get output via java regex?

Comment: I doubt `Like 'what's this'` is valid here. Shouldn't it be `Like 'what\'s this'`? Or `Like 'what''s this'`?

Comment: i can't limit the user input, but i think i can preprocess it as you suggest

Comment: User input? Then why do you need a regex to extract anything if the string you want to parse is built by you?

Comment: i'm working on a common query library, front end combine user's inputs to a string like input sample then send to me as a string parameter , however, i need to further process on each of the `AND` conditions

Comment: @aqiao Is it guaranteed that the statement will start with `and`? (Forget the case)

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder, sure ! Each of the condition must starts with `and`, it's convention by design

Comment: @aqiao So... I have deleted my old answer and have added a new one. It was a real bich to use the for loop to parse each letter, but hopefully it works now :)

Comment: And forget about the LinkedList stuff. Turns out it wasn't necessary.

Comment: To be honnest, you are stuck with a `String` query to be able to exact the condition with a regex; which means you can't use a `PreparedStatement` but seems the input his from users. It isn't safe to use a `Statement` with user inputs. **See about SQL Injection!** Now, if you have a correct `PreparedStatement`, you can still try to extract the condition an get the parameter passed to the `PreparedStatement` but this won't be done just with a regex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
String s = "And condition 1 here and tbl.col2 like '%Test' AND tbl.col3 >='2018-12-12' And tbl.col4 Like 'what\\'s this'";

s = s.trim();
s = s.substring(3).trim();

boolean exclude = false;

s = s + " and";

String str = "";

for(int i = 0; i < s.length()-3; i++)
{
    if( s.charAt(i) == '\'' && !(s.charAt(i-1) == '\\') )
    {
        exclude = !exclude;
    }
    
    if((!s.substring(i, i+3).equalsIgnoreCase("and") || exclude) && (i != s.length()-4))
    {
        str += s.charAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(str);
        str = "";
        i += 3;
    }
}
```

**Note -** The above code should work for pretty much any condition type, but as Wiktor has mentioned in the comments, you'll need to use `'what\\'s this'` instead of `'what's this'`

## Explanation -

When exclude is `true`, it means that the letters (and essentially words) being checked are within ' '. Hence, `str` stores ANY AND ALL characters within the ' ', including the notorious `and`

`i < s.length() - 3` means that the characters being checked and stored will be those before three letters of the end of the String. It's important, because we have added an `" and"` to `s` previously.

Now, if the letter at `i` is `'`, and is not preceded by a `\`, then the value of `exclude` is reversed i.e. if the system was being told to include all words, even `and`, then it is told not to, now. Hence, any `and` within quotations is captured using this method.

`if((!s.substring(i, i+3).equalsIgnoreCase("and") || exclude) && (i != s.length()-4))` is a **very tedious** way to say that if the letter is not part of an `and` *separator*, (or if it the last letter of the final condition), then it should be stored in `str`.

It's quite difficult to type out the best explanation possible, but I'm sure if you read the code long and hard enough, then you'll understand it better.

Comment: Thanks Coder and sorry for response! Works like a charm, looks it's difficult to use pure regex to do this.